# Unwanted page reload after FB.api call

Tags: javascript, facebook, coffeescript

I have a problem using the Facebook api with coffeescript.
Each time I do `FB.getLoginStatus` and the status is `"connected"`, I call `FB.api("/me", (data)->console.log(data))` the page reload automatically without me asking for it.

And another problem is that a get an error from Facebook if place a breakpoint after the `console.log` call and watch for the value of data.

I would like to know if I do this ok, and overall why do the page reload.

Here is the coffeescript code for the page:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init
    appId: document.getElementById("fb-root").getAttribute("data-app-id")
    channelUrl: document.getElementById("fb-root").getAttribute("data-channel-url")
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', (response) ->
    window.location = window.location
  )
  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()
  FB.getLoginStatus((data) ->
     console.log(data)
     if (data.status == "connected")
      uid = data.authResponse.userID
      accessToken = data.authResponse.accessToken;
      FB.api("/me", (data) ->
        console.log(data) // Here is the last call before the reload
      )
     else if (data.status == "not_authorized")
        console.log("Je suis log a facebook")
        $("#FBConnect").on("click", (e) ->
            FB.login( (response) ->
              if response.authResponse
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me', (response) ->
                  console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                )
              else
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            )
        )
      # the user is logged in to Facebook,
      # but has not authenticated your app
     else
        console.log("Je ne suis pas connecte a facebook")
      # the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  )

PageScript = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]
return if document.getElementById("FBScript")
FBScript = document.createElement("script")
FBScript.id = "FBScript"
FBScript.async = true
FBScript.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
PageScript.parentNode.insertBefore(FBScript, PageScript)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page reload might be due to following line in your code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', (response) ->
    window.location = window.location
)
```

`auth.login` is fired when the `auth` status changes from `unknown` to `connected`, so when you are connected, the code executes and as you are reloading the page within that function, the page gets reloaded. Removing the line:: `window.location = window.location` should resolve it.

Comment: Thank you, did not noticed this line since i copied this... Thank you again.